# Elderly man in futuristic city, living different lives in different times

Tags: story-identification, movie

I just remember a few scenes from the beginning, where a person lives different situations in different times and places.

Apparently he is an old man in a futuristic city, but I can't remember anything else.

I would like to continue that movie, but I don't remember its name.  Can anyone identify this movie?

Edit: I can only add that by the aesthetics it appeared to be a recent movie (from 2005 onwards more or less)

Comment: When did you see the movie?  Where (to the best of your knowledge) was it made?  What did the elderly guy look like?  ..  More details, even trivial or seemingly meaningless ones, might help people identify it.

Comment: I remember this. He's basically suffering from a form of advanced alzheimers or something and doesn't realise he's living in the future. He needs it explaining to him.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the 2009 film "[Mr Nobody](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0485947/)".

> In the year 2092, one hundred eighteen year old Nemo is recounting his
>   life story to a reporter. He is less than clear, often times thinking
>   that he is only thirty-four years of age. But his story becomes more
>   confusing after he does focus on the fact of his current real age. He
>   tells of his life at three primary points in his life: at age nine
>   (when his parents divorced), age sixteen and age thirty-four. The
>   confusing aspect of the story is that he tells of alternate life
>   paths, often changing course with the flick of a decision at each of
>   those ages. One life path has him ultimately married to Elise, a
>   depressed woman who never got over the unrequited love she had for a
>   guy named Stefano when she was a teenager and who asked Nemo to swear
>   that when she died he would sprinkle her ashes on Mars. A second life
>   path has him married to Jean. Their life is one of luxury but one also
>   of utter boredom.

Comment: Heck yes! you people are awesome!! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys for mentioning this movie. Never heard of it until tonight... just watched it and it's indeed awesome.

Answer (score 5):

I don't suppose it was *[Cloud Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Atlas_%28film%29)* with Tom Hanks and Halle Berry?

In this film, various actors play up to six different characters, all in different eras starting in the 1800s up through some future time with different calendars.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not the one I am looking for. However, thanks to you I have found a great movie to see ;)